USSD Command on 4G module
I have an AirM2M_Air724UG_V301840_LTE_AT module with ^HVER: RDA8910. I'm encountering an error when attempting to send a USSD command. Here are the details of my current status:
AT+CREG? -> +CREG: 0,1 OK 
AT+CSQ -> +CSQ: 26,99 OK 
AT+CNMI? -> +CNMI: 2,2,0,0,0 OK 
AT+CSCS="GSM" -> OK 
AT+CMEE=2 -> OK 
AT+COPS? -> +COPS: 0,1,"IranCell",7 OK 
AT+CUSD? -> +CUSD: 0 OK 
AT+CUSD=1 -> OK 
AT+CUSD=1,"7332#",15 -> +CME ERROR: phone failure 
AT+CMGF=1 -> OK 
AT+COPS=3,1 -> OK 
AT+CUSD=1,"7332#",15 -> +CME ERROR: phone failure 
AT+CNMI=2,1,2,1,1 -> OK 
AT+CUSD=1,"7332#",15 -> +CME ERROR: phone failure 
AT+CUSD=1,"7332#",32 -> +CME ERROR: parameters are invalid 
AT+CUSD=1,"7332#" -> +CME ERROR: phone failure 
AT+CUSD=0,"7332#"-> +CME ERROR: phone failure
How can I fix this issue?
Additional Information:
I have a 2G module (Goouuu tech GA6) that works with this SIM card, so the SIM card is fine.
All other commands work; I can make calls, send and receive SMS, and connect to the network. The USSD command is the only one that fails.
